# recursive function with user input

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am writing up a silly little script to help me assign ratings to movies in my collection. I have an array of movie titles that need sorting. I want to apply a merge-sort-like recursive algorithm to sort the movies by rating. At each comparison, I want a form on the document to be updated. The user will select either A or B -- the better of the two titles -- and then click a "continue" button. It will use this information to proceed with the sort. By the end of the process, the user will have answered A or B to the minimum number of binary comparison questions required to produce an ordered list of the movies.

My problem: how can I have the recursive algorithm wait on the input from the form for each step? Using something like `confirm()` would allow the code to block while input is determined, but obviously page elements can't do this. Should I involve some nasty timeout function? Keep some kind of global closure? Ideally, I want the "continue" button to be linked to a continueRecursion() callback, but I have no idea how to do this.

Any suggestions on how to attack this?

Comment: The data structure that is used to represent recursion is the `Stack`.  (This makes sense, because the programmatic stack is a stack.)  So make a stack data structure, and then store emulated local variables representing each function call on each level of the stack.  Then put that stack in a global variable - and hopefully you see where this is going ...

Answer (score 1):

Just store the result between function calls and have the user be the one who initiates the routine.

So:

1. Get data
2. Present choice
3. Upon user's selection, give present choice + old data to sort routine.
4. After sort present data to step 1 and continue again.

You'll just need to hold the data in a global or keep passing it around.